# When to use CodingKeys in Decodable(Swift)

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

Let's say I want to decode a Person struct as follows.

```
struct Person: Decodable {

let firstName: String
let lastName: String
let age: Int: String
}
```

I understand that the data can be decoded only with above. Therefore if I'm not changing the properties to a custom name if there no difference between the above and below implementation?

Further is there other cases where you want to use CodingKeys? I'm confused when they are necessary other than for renaming purposes.

```
struct Person: Decodable {

let firstName: String
let lastName: String
let age: Int: String
}

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        
        case firstName
        case lastName
        case age
}
```

Comment: You want to use coding keys where the key in the JSON does not match the property of the object/struct.  Ie if instead of `firstName`, the property was `FirstName` or `First Name` or some other combination, you'd need to use `CodingKey` to map between them - [for example](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/119/codable-cheat-sheet)

Comment: You use `CodingKeys` when your dataset contains a key name that cannot be directly used in your model.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Is it possible to use init(from decoder: Decoder) {} and decoder.container without using CodingKeys?

Comment: @mendokusai Yes, it's possible, in rare instances. You can decode unkeyed objects, for example (that is, arrays). There is nothing special about `CodingKeys`, they are just constants for keys that can be generated automatically by the compiler.

Comment: `data can be decoded only with above` - not entirely correct, you can decode via other means also, just that you'll have to write more code.

Comment: `let age: Int: String` is not legal Swift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all there is a make-or-break rule for using `CodingKeys`:

- You can omit `CodingKeys` completely if the JSON – or whatever `Codable` conforming format – keys match exactly the corresponding properties (like in your example) or the conversion is covered by an appropriate [`keyDecodingStrategy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy).
- Otherwise you have to specify **all** `CodingKeys` you need to be decoded (see also reason #3 below).

---

There are three major reasons to use `CodingKeys`:

1. A Swift variable/property name must not start with a number. If a key does start with a number you have to specify a compatible `CodingKey` to be able to decode the key at all.
2. You want to use a different property name.
3. You want to exclude keys from being decoded for example an `id` property which is not in the JSON and is initialized with an `UUID` constant.

And `CodingKeys` are mandatory if you implement `init(from decoder` to decode a **keyed** container.

Comment: While the above is largely true, `Codable` itself has no relationship with JSON. If a `Codable` type is used with a JSON decoder/encoder, then that's applicable, but otherwise has no relevance. There are many other types of decoders/encoders including one provided by Apple for property lists.

Answer (score 6):

You can use CodingKeys in different ways for example, when you know that at least one of the name of values that you are expecting in your JSON is actually different from your "let or var" name.

Example:

```
struct Person: Decodable {

let firstName: String
let lastName: String
let age: Int: String
}

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName
        case age
}
```

Other case is when you are using class inheritance.

In conclusion, if you are absolutely sure that you are using the same variable name as your encoding key(JSON), you can omit it (but if you want to put it, it doesn't matter), but if there's a difference, maybe a change of your codingKeys like an uppercase or using different words, you should use the enum to map the correct key with the variable name.

Answer (score 1):

CodingKeys can be extremely helpful if you have a JSON with arbitrary number  of coding keys (also called dynamic keys). Here is an example.

```
import UIKit
// Consider JSON with infinite number of keys: "S001", "S002" and so on
let jsonData = """
{
  "S001": {
    "firstName": "Tony",
    "lastName": "Stark"
  },
  "S002": {
    "firstName": "Peter",
    "lastName": "Parker"
  },
  "S003": {
    "firstName": "Bruce",
    "lastName": "Wayne"
  }
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!



struct Student: Decodable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
}

struct DecodedArray: Decodable {

    var array: [Student]
    
    // Define DynamicCodingKeys type needed for creating
    // decoding container from JSONDecoder
    private struct DynamicCodingKeys: CodingKey {

        // Use for string-keyed dictionary
        var stringValue: String
        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }

        // Use for integer-keyed dictionary
        var intValue: Int?
        init?(intValue: Int) {
            // We are not using this, thus just return nil
            return nil
        }
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        // 1
        // Create a decoding container using DynamicCodingKeys
        // The container will contain all the JSON first level key
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: DynamicCodingKeys.self)

        var tempArray = [Student]()

        // 2
        // Loop through each key (student ID) in container
        for key in container.allKeys {

            // Decode Student using key & keep decoded Student object in tempArray
            let decodedObject = try container.decode(Student.self, forKey: DynamicCodingKeys(stringValue: key.stringValue)!)
            tempArray.append(decodedObject)
        }

        // 3
        // Finish decoding all Student objects. Thus assign tempArray to array.
        array = tempArray
    }
}

let decodedResult = try! JSONDecoder().decode(DecodedArray.self, from: jsonData)
```

Comment: In your example actually you don't need to create a custom CodingKey nor implement `init(from decoder`. Decode `let decodedResult = try! JSONDecoder().decode([String:Student].self, from: jsonData)` and get the values `let array = Array(decodedResult.values)`.Or for a sorted result sort the keys and get their values in order with `map`.

Comment: Good catch, @vadian. Just wanted to demonstrate the presence of dynamic coding keys. They are sometimes used to to merge data from different depths and transform data while decoding/encoding.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore if I'm not changing the properties to a custom name if there no difference between the above and below implementation?

Yes, but there's a bit of misunderstanding here. The two implementations you have are *literally* identical because in the second one the `CodingKeys` enum would never be used. To be used, the enum must be nested within the `Decodable` conforming type (`Person` in this case):

```swift
struct Person: Decodable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let age: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {    
        case firstName
        case lastName
        case age
    }
}
```

There is in practice no difference between this implementation and the ones you provided.

---

> Further is there other cases where you want to use CodingKeys?

CodingKeys are not used solely by Decodable, they are also used by Encodable. When using Encodable, a reason to use CodingKeys is to specify only a subset of the instances fields should be serialized.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible cases during Decoding.

With this example, I'll bring all 3 examples so you can understand when you need  `CodingKey`.

Let's say you have your `Json` response as below:

```json
{
    Firstname: "Tom"
    Lastname: "Cruise"
    age: 34
}
```

And your structure Model is as follows:

```swift
struct Person: Codable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let age: Int
    var hobby: String? // You want to set the value manually from some other source other than the `json` data
}
```

**Use-cases**

1. You want to keep the property name `age` as it is.
2. You want to change `Firstname`-> `firstName` and `Lastname`->`lastName`.
3. You don't want to take the `hobby` from json, you want to manually set/update the value from other sources.

To meet your these 3 cases you will add the Coding Keys as follows:

```swift
struct Person: Codable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let age: Int
    var hobby: String? // Optional hobby which will be ignored during decoding

    // Here's your answer:
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName = "Firstname"
        case lastName = "Lastname"
        case age
        //case hobby // It will be ignored during decoding
    }
}
```

So **if you have use-case 2 and/or 3 then you need `CodingKey`. If you have only use-case 1 the you don't need `CodingKey`**.